# Inquiry about try-with-resources statement

Tags: java, resources, try-catch

Just confirming that the following does not compile and it's not a mistake of mine:

```
try(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/TryItOutMan.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())
        {
        }
        catch(IOException io){io.printStackTrace();}
```

However the following compiles:

```
try(BufferedWriter bw =Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/TryItOutMan.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())
        {
        }
        catch(IOException io){io.printStackTrace();}
```

It seems that the compiler check whether or not the classes declared in the try-catch-with-resources statement implement `AutoClosable`... however It could have worked since the method returns a `BufferedWriter` which implements `AutoClosable`.

Just asking for a confirmation that

try(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/TryItOutMan.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset())

does not compile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you open a file if you didn't intend to use it for anything?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I see, however I am studying for the OCPJP7 and I need to be careful to this kind of subtle things. It's also legal to declare a variable "static transient" which logically I would think it's not.

Comment: The compiler tends not to understand features which are specific to a library.  A `static transient` field doesn't make sense due to the way the Serialization library works, but the JLS doesn't know that.  In theory you can develop a serialization library which supports serialization of static fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the syntax definition of the try-with-resources [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), you will see that it expects a variable name. So it must look like:

```
try (SomeType variable = xxx;)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) states:

> The `try`-with-resources statement is a `try` statement that declares one or more resources.

In your first snippet, you don't declare a resource:

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/TryItOutMan.txt")
```

Whilst in your second snippet, you do:

```
BufferedWriter bw = ....
```